# In PhpStorm warning method 'withJson' not found (Slim Framework)

Tags: php, phpstorm, slim, slim-3

In PhpStorm I get the warning message 
"warning method 'withJson' not found" in \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface" at te line:

```
return $response->withJson($toReturn, 200);
```

The code:

```
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;


$app->get('/bedrijven', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    require_once(CLASSES_PATH . "/class_bedrijven.php");
    $Bedrijven = new Bedrijven();

    $toReturn = $Bedrijven->get_bedrijven();
    return $response->withJson($toReturn, 200);
});
```

I already updated slim framework with composer to latest version 3.8.1 and added Slim as a plugin in PhpStorm.
The Vendor directorie is set to Sources and Excluded.

The only answer I can find is to turn off the warning messages in PhpStorm in Editor -> Inspections -> PHP -> Undefined -> undefined method.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: There is no `withJson()` method in `\Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface` or parent interface -- https://github.com/php-fig/http-message/blob/master/src/ResponseInterface.php . So it must be implemented additionally in concrete ResponseInterface implementation class (e.g. in Slim framework classes). IDE is absolutely correct here.

Comment: It isn't just a PhpStorm issue, is it? I mean, the code itself doesn't run either, does it?

Comment: That was the strange thing. I could not find the `withJson()` either, but is does work fine. The solution was given by @Nima in the answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Method `withJson` is not defined in `\Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface` but in `Slim\Http\Response` (which implements the former), that means this method is something related to Slim framework. You can try this:

```
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Slim\Http\Response as Response;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! After hours of searching you came with the correct answer.

Comment: Following the above change in object, if you have any previous calls to `$response->getBody()->write()`, you want to replace them with simpler `$response->write()` writing.